# UFW Ubuntu Enabled And Cannot Access Via SSH port

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I accidentally enabled the UFW on my -Google Cloud Platform- Ubuntu instance and unfortunately, port 22 is blocked now. I've tried every way to go inside the VM but I can't. I tried to access through the serial port but it's asking me for user and password that was never set. I also have tried to make new firewall rules to allowing telnet port from my Windows Command prompt but it didn't work. Does anyone have any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Compute Engine instance, you could use the [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to disable ufw on your Ubuntu instance. I found a helpful answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50017798/10553701) for you. While trying to connect using serial port, did you follow [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console)?

If you are using App Engine Flexible, how did you set up UFW? Did you SSH in and configure firewall or used the [App Engine Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/creating-firewalls)?

In any case you could always create a new VM, this is the philosophy of Cloud Computing that rather spending time on troubleshooting/debugging create a new VM and shutdown the existing one. The other option for you would be to create a private issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491299&template=1161102) with your project-id, instance name and other details you feel relevant and wait for the engineers at Google to respond.